# Using negative lookbehind in R

Tags: r, regex-lookarounds

I have these strings in a folder. Assume there are other similar files in this folder.

```
 [3] "/farm/chickens_industrial_meat_location_df.csv"   
 [4] "farm/goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv"
```

I am trying to extract the files with string `location_df` while excluding the files with the string `chickens` & `location_df`.

I thought I could do this by typing: `list.files(pattern = "location_df(?<!(chickens))"`

My understanding is that using a negative lookaround would remove strings that have `chickens`. What am I not understanding about regex here and what is the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `grepl` would be

```
str1[!grepl('chickens_.*location_df', str1) & grepl('location_df', str1)]
#[1] "farm/goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv"
```

Or more simplified version would be

```
str1[!grepl('chickens_', str1) & grepl('location_df', str1)]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("/farm/chickens_industrial_meat_location_df.csv",
        "farm/goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv" )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> list.files(pattern = "location_df")
[1] "chickens_industrial_meat_location_df.csv" "goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv"    

> setdiff(list.files(pattern = "location_df"), list.files(pattern = "chickens"))
[1] "goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv"

> setdiff(list.files(pattern = "location_df"), list.files(pattern = "goats"))
[1] "chickens_industrial_meat_location_df.csv"
```

According to the R-helpfile for regex, *"...functions which use regular expressions (often via the use of grep) include apropos, browseEnv, help.search, **list.files** and ls. These will all use extended regular expressions."* (ERE).

Reading the above indicates that the `list.files()` and `list.dirs()` functions do not implement lookarounds which are generally available with Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE). A tiny clue is that the R-helpfile for `list.files()` / `list.dirs()` doesn't include the option `perl=TRUE`.

So instead of lookarounds, the code shown above uses `setdiff()` to help you interrogate a directory. Of course, with the code above the two regex 'tokens' you're searching for can appear in any order, but you can help yourself out by searching for "location_df.csv" or "location_df.csv$" (since the ".csv" extension would come at the end of the filename, and the `$` -zerowidth assertion would similarly anchor the pattern to the end of the string). You could also try using `^` to anchor "chickens" or "goats" to the beginning of the string. Putting it all together gives the code below:

```
> setdiff(list.files(pattern = "location_df.csv$"), list.files(pattern = "^chickens"))
[1] "goats_grassland_meat_location_df.csv"

> setdiff(list.files(pattern = "location_df.csv$"), list.files(pattern = "^goats"))
[1] "chickens_industrial_meat_location_df.csv"
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html
https://www.r-project.org/